Tips on generating entangled photon pair with SPDC entanglement source
In my summer lab, me and my labmates are trying to generate entangled photon pairs using a spontaneous parametric down-conversion (SPDC) entanglement source with BBO crystals. We're using a 405 nm diode laser from Matchbox with model number 405L-21A.
Our setup is as follows: we shine the laser through the SPDC entanglement source, and it is supposed to produce a pair of entangled photons (one is 847 nm and the other is 776 nm) and send them into one end of a fiber optic. The other end directs the entangled photons into a 50/50 beamsplitter. On one output side of the beamsplitter, we placed a filter that lets through 780 nm light and then a photon detector, and on the other output side, we placed a filter that lets through 850 nm light and then a photon detector. To detect entanglement, we are looking to see coincidences in the two detectors.
We're having trouble producing entangled photons, and we suspect that the laser, entanglement source, and fiber optic aren't aligned properly. What are some tips for aligning these?

By "entangled," do you mean "perfectly correlated"? If not, why else would they be used in experiments? Achieving perfect correlation between a pair of photons involves aligning every property a photon possesses, not just the obvious ones like speed, direction, and polarization. Frequency, phase, and timing are equally crucial. The pair you are attempting to create will be fundamentally flawed because they lack correlation, particularly given their different frequencies.

They're polarization entangled and time correlated

They're not correlated if they have different frequencies, and there's no way to guaranty  coincidences.

@BillAlsept photons with different wavelengths can be entangled. There have been experiments reported in the literature that have used such scenarios.

Do you use type II phase matching?

BBO photons exit the crystal on its opposite sides (symmetry)... ensure you are collecting from both sides  ....

@flippiefanus we use type I phase matching

How do you get polarization entanglement with type I phase matching?
